# mat-hint svgicon not showing any text

Tags: angular

I have following code in angular it showing only svg icon and not showing text. I am trying to get output something like   [1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJmQh.png

There is any other component than mat-hint which gives me same output as per image?

```
<mat-hint
    *ngIf="hashOptions.placeholder=='Account Name'"
  >
  <mat-icon svgIcon="Application_Information">Note: All accounts created for organizational purposes</mat-icon>
  </mat-hint>
```

Comment: Can you show how this JSON is used in your Angular project?

Comment: modified with exact issue

Comment: So the svg icon is showing up? Are you using the mat-hint together with a input field? 
I think writing text between the <mat-icon> tags will not work.
I would try this:

`<mat-hint *ngIf="hashOptions.placeholder=='Account Name'">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="Application_Information"></mat-icon>
Note:All accounts created for organizational purposes
  </mat-hint>`